# Steganography/Execute command

Tags: command-line, bash, png

I made a program that encrypts commands and executes on the remote system, but after that I wanted to learn steganography and I have one question: Is it possible to attach a script to a PNG or JPG or BMP or other files on Ubuntu and execute that script, for example it's possible to attach a JS code to a PDF file. Please, help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to attach a script to a PNG or JPG or BMP or other files on Ubuntu and execute that script.

No. Differently from Windows Linux/Ubuntu extension are only for us humans. Linux/Ubuntu checks the 1st few bits to determine the "file signature".

Adding a script to a file ending on `.png` would not make it an image. It would make it a script ending on `.png`.

> for example it's possible to attach a JS code to a PDF file

See [the Adbobe JS API reference](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf).

Comment: Thank you, but is it possible to attach a batch script to an image file and open it on Windows?